# Understand Binding DataGridComboBoxColumn Itemssource and SelectedItem

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, combobox

I do not understand how the binding to a DataGridComboBoxColumn works correctly.
My DataGrid TextColum displays the Value from my RowEntries but the ComboBoxColumn is unfilled.

I have a ObservableCollection of RowEntryView named RowEntries which are derived:

```
public class DataTypes : RowEntryView
{
    private string _value;
    public string[] ValuesPossible {get; set; }
    public string Value 
    {
        get
        {
            return _value;
        }

        set
        {
            _value = value;
             OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Value"));
        }
    }
}
```

My DatagridTextColum displays the Value variable. My DataGridComboBoxColumn is blank. Values possible is filled with {"A", "B", "C"}, Value is filled with "A"

```
<DataTemplate x:Name="myDataTemplate">
       <DataGrid RowHeight="30" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" x:Name="myDataGridMain" CanUserAddRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding RowEntries}" >
       <DataGrid.Columns>    
       <DataGridTextColumn Width="4*" IsReadOnly="True" x:Name="dataGridColumnDescription" Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value}">
       </DataGridTextColumn>
       <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Type" ItemsSource="{Binding ValuesPossible}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Value}"></DataGridComboBoxColumn>
                 </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </DataTemplate>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then I would suggest to use DataGridTemplateColumn:

```
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Type">
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ComboBox   ItemsSource="{Binding ValuesPossible}"
                                                    SelectedItem="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"></ComboBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <TextBlock  Text="{Binding}"></TextBlock>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

ItempsSource is the list of items you wand to be displayed. SelectedItem(not selectedItemBinding) is your selected object. Basically you need to have SelectedItem="{Binding Value}".
Now, to be able to notify you datacontext about the change on each new selection, your object has to implement INotifyPropertyChanged and then your binding will become:
SelectedItem="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}".
You will find a lot of examples on the net.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: SelectedItem is not available on DataGridComboBoxColum and INotifychanged is implemented in RowEntryView